# C# BinaryReader ReadUTF from Java's DataOutputStream

Tags: java, c#, input, io, output

I've been working on converting the classes over to C# (**DataInputStream** and **DataOutputStream**) and I've finished the DataOutputStream class, now the problems are all sitting in the InputStream class.

**Note: The reason that I'm not using the Encoding class in C# is because DataInput/DataOutputStream in Java use a custom UTF-8 Encoding.**

Basically, I have this code: (**C#**) which uses the **BinaryReader** class

```
public String ReadUTF()
    {
        int utflen = this.ReadUnsignedShort ();
        byte[] bytearr = null;
        char[] chararr = null;

        if(bytearr.Length < utflen)
        {
            bytearr = new byte[utflen * 2];
            chararr = new char[utflen * 2];
        }

        int c, char2, char3;
        int count = 0;
        int chararr_count=0;

        this.ReadFully(bytearr, 0, utflen);

        while (count < utflen) {
            c = (int) bytearr[count] & 0xff;
            if (c > 127) break;
            count++;
            chararr[chararr_count++]=(char)c;
        }

        while (count < utflen) {
            c = (int) bytearr[count] & 0xff;
            switch (c >> 4) {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
                /* 0xxxxxxx*/
                count++;
                chararr[chararr_count++]=(char)c;
                break;
            case 12: case 13:
                /* 110x xxxx   10xx xxxx*/
                count += 2;
                if (count > utflen)
                    throw new Exception(
                        "malformed input: partial character at end");
                char2 = (int) bytearr[count-1];
                if ((char2 & 0xC0) != 0x80)
                    throw new Exception(
                        "malformed input around byte " + count);
                chararr[chararr_count++]=(char)(((c & 0x1F) << 6) |
                                                (char2 & 0x3F));
                break;
            case 14:
                /* 1110 xxxx  10xx xxxx  10xx xxxx */
                count += 3;
                if (count > utflen)
                    throw new Exception(
                        "malformed input: partial character at end");
                char2 = (int) bytearr[count-2];
                char3 = (int) bytearr[count-1];
                if (((char2 & 0xC0) != 0x80) || ((char3 & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                    throw new Exception(
                        "malformed input around byte " + (count-1));
                chararr[chararr_count++]=(char)(((c     & 0x0F) << 12) |
                                                ((char2 & 0x3F) << 6)  |
                                                ((char3 & 0x3F) << 0));
                break;
            default:
                /* 10xx xxxx,  1111 xxxx */
                throw new Exception(
                    "malformed input around byte " + count);
            }
        }
        // The number of chars produced may be less than utflen
        return new String(chararr, 0, chararr_count);
    }
```

here's my **ReadUnsignedShort** method

```
public int ReadUnsignedShort()
    {
        int ch1 = BinaryReader.Read();
        int ch2 = BinaryReader.Read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2) < 0)
        {
            throw new EndOfStreamException(); // Temp- To be changed
        }
        return (ch1 << 8) + (ch2 << 0); 
    }
```

**Here's the Readfully method too that's used:**

```
public void ReadFully(byte[] b, int off, int len)
    {
        if(len < 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }

        int n = 0;
        while(n < len) 
        {
            int count = ClientInput.Read(b, off + n, len - n);
            if(count < 0)
            {
                throw new EndOfStreamException(); // Temp - to be changed
            }
            n += count;
        }
    }
```

With the OutputStream the problem was that I was using the Write(int) instead of the Write(byte) function, but I don't think that's the case here, either that or I must be blind.

If you're interested in how the UTF String is sent, here's the C# Conversion for it:

```
public int WriteUTF(string str)
    {
        int strlen = str.Length;
        int utflen = 0;
        int c, count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) 
        {
            c = str.ToCharArray()[i];
            if((c >= 0x0001) && (c <= 0x007F)) 
            {
                utflen++;
            } 
            else if(c > 0x07FF)
            {
                utflen += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                utflen += 2;
            }
        }

        if(utflen > 65535)
        {
            throw new Exception("Encoded string is too long: " + utflen + " bytes");
        }

        byte[] bytearr = null;
        bytearr = new byte[(utflen*2) + 2];

        bytearr[count++] = (byte) (((uint)utflen >> 8) & 0xFF);
        bytearr[count++] = (byte) (((uint)utflen >> 0) & 0xFF);

        int x = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < strlen; x++) 
        {
            c = str.ToCharArray()[x];
            if (!((c >= 0x0001) && (c <= 0x007F))) break;
            bytearr[count++] = (byte)c;
        }

        for(;x < strlen; x++)
        {
            c = str.ToCharArray()[x];
            if ((c >= 0x0001) && (c <= 0x007F)) 
            {
                bytearr[count++] = (byte)c;
            }
            else if (c > 0x07FF)
            {
                bytearr[count++] = (byte) (0xE0 | ((c >> 12) & 0x0F));
                bytearr[count++] = (byte) (0x80 | ((c >>  6) & 0x3F));
                bytearr[count++] = (byte) (0x80 | ((c >>  0) & 0x3F));
            }
            else
            {
                bytearr[count++] = (byte) (0xC0 | ((c >>  6) & 0x1F));
                bytearr[count++] = (byte) (0x80 | ((c >>  0) & 0x3F));
            }
        }
        ClientOutput.Write (bytearr, 0, utflen+2);
        return utflen + 2;
    }
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information to get a little help with reading the UTF Values, this is really putting a road-block in my progress rate for my project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

have written a C# Conversion of Java's **DataInputStream** and **DataOutputStream** you can collect them here.

https://bitbucket.org/CTucker1327/c-datastreams/src

To construct these classes you would pass a BinaryWriter or BinaryReader into the constructor.

To Construct DataOutputStream

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BinaryWriter(Stream));
```

To Construct DataInputStream

```
DataInptuStream in = new DataInputStream(new BinaryReader(Stream));
```

Comment: if the responses here were not helpful but you were able to solve the problem on your own, it would be nice for you to follow up your own question with the answer, in case someone else finds themselves in a similar situation in the future. If any of the responses here _were_ helpful, you should comment on how and why, and of course mark/up-vote any useful answers to identify them. Thanks! (It's great you've put the source online, but that's elsewhere and in any case won't specifically call out what the actual problem(s) was(were)).

Comment: The link is dead... Could you share the code somewhere else?

Comment: https://github.com/cping/LGame/tree/master/C%23/Loon2Unity/Loon.Java

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the "question" correctly (such as it is — you say there's a "roadblock" but you fail to explain what exactly the "roadblock" is), you are trying to implement in C# the code to read and write text from the stream. If so, then (and I know if you're new to .NET this isn't immediately obvious) explicitly handling the text encoding yourself is insane.

BinaryReader and BinaryWriter have methods to handle this. When you create the objects, you can pass an Encoding instance (e.g. System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, etc.) which is used to interpret or create binary data for text. You can use BinaryReader.ReadChars(int) to read text, and BinaryWriter.Write(char[]) to write text.

If for some reason that doesn't work, at the very least you can use an Encoding instance directly to interpret or create binary data for some text. Encoding.GetString(byte[]) will convert binary to text, and Encoding.GetBytes(string) will convert text to binary. Again, using a specific Encoding instance for the actual text encoding you're dealing with.

Comment: The reason that I'm doing this is because the `DataOutputStream` class that I use in my Java server uses custom UTF-8 encryption, so when I sent a UTF String from the server, the encording that it uses it different than standard UTF-8 Encoding. The problem here is that it's not reading the data properly, for whatever reason it's not returning the value of the String... or even getting anywhere for that matter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286366%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: To elaborate on why I'm doing this, My Server Structure that I've been writing uses the Java `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` classes, I'm now writing a Client in C# which needs to be able to communicate with the server without problems, considering the Java classes use custom encoding for UTF-8, that's why I'm handling everything myself as far as the encoding goes.

Comment: If I understand the Java implementation correctly, the only difference between it and a plain UTF8 encoding is the two-byte prefix indicating the byte count for the remaining data. So just read those two bytes as an Int16, and then use that byte count to determine the length of bytes to read after that, then pass those bytes to Encoding.UTF8.GetString(). Obviously you would do the inverse of that for writing the string.